Speech Recognition Profile Training using SAPI 5.4
I am developing a c++ DLL that is used by a c# app via interop.  The DLL's purpose is to train the "Default" speech recognition profile.  The c# app only sends Training Text and receives notifications of completion of each Training file, so that it can send the next Training Text.  A user reads the Training Text in the c# app and the c++ DLL handles the recognition.
I've read several articles and designed the flow of this code based on the description from Eric Brown here.  There are examples of using existing wav files to accomplish this, however, the goal is to replicate what Windows does with speech profile training.
I've pasted the complete code below, with Error handling, Header file with C wrapper, and c# code omitted, with the hope that someone can help.
The following issues are encountered:

The .wav file is created, but does not play.  The file can be opened
in audio editing software and appears to have a really fast playback
speed.
Reading a second Training Text (i.e. StarListening), the wav file is
overwritten.
AppendTranscript results in FAILED (error p!=0).

Global Variables:
CComPtr <ISpRecognizer2> cpRecognizer2;
CComPtr<ISpRecognizer> cpRecognizer;
CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> cpProfileToken;
CComPtr<ISpRecoContext> cpRecoContext;
CComPtr<ISpRecoGrammar> cpRecoGrammar;
CComPtr<ISpAudio> cpAudio;
CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> cpObjectToken;
CComPtr<ISpTranscript> cpTranscript;
CComPtr<ISpObjectToken> cpRecoProfile;
CComPtr<ISpRecoResult> cpRecoResult;
CComPtr<ISpStream> cpStream;
CComPtr<ISpStreamFormat> cpStreamFormat;


WCHAR *pwszRecoProfileName;
WCHAR* pwszRecoResultText;
CSpDynamicString TrText;

ULONG CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA = 28;
ULONG CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE = 32768;

LoopFunciton to handle recognition and wav file creation based on default Speech Profile.

void LoopFunction()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    while (running.load()) {
        // Wait for recognition events
        CSpEvent spEvent;
        while (spEvent.GetFrom(cpRecoContext) == S_OK)
        {
            if (spEvent.eEventId == SPEI_RECOGNITION)
            {
                // Get the reco result
                cpRecoResult = spEvent.RecoResult();
                // release recognition result pointer in event object
                spEvent.Clear();
                StopListening();

                // if recognition received, and result stored then store the audio
                if (cpRecoResult)
                {
                    //GetStorageFileName retrieves the object token file name from the registry.
                    LPWSTR lpFileName;
                    hr = cpObjectToken->GetStorageFileName(CLSID_NULL, L"TrainingAudio.wav", L"TrainingAudio\\ESTE_%d.wav", CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, &lpFileName);

                    // Get da recognized text
                    hr = cpRecoResult->GetText(SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, SP_GETWHOLEPHRASE, FALSE, &pwszRecoResultText, NULL);

                    // get stream pointer to recognized audio
                    hr = cpRecoResult->GetAudio(0, 0, &cpStreamFormat);

                    // Create a stream object
                    hr = cpStream.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpStream);

                    // create file on hard-disk for storing recognized audio, and Bind the stream to the file
                    hr = cpStream->BindToFile(lpFileName, SPFM_CREATE_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL, SPFEI_ALL_EVENTS);

                    ULONG cbWritten = 0;

                    //Continuously transfer data between the two streams until no more data is found (i.e. end of stream)                 
                    while (TRUE)
                    {
                        STATSTG stats;
                        hr = cpStreamFormat->Stat(&stats, NULL);

                        BYTE bBuffer[1000];
                        ULONG cbRead;

                        hr = cpStreamFormat->Read(bBuffer, 1000, &cbRead);

                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && cbRead > 0)
                        {
                            hr = cpStream->Write(bBuffer, cbRead, &cbWritten);
                        }

                        if (cbRead < 1000)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Use QueryInterface on the stream object to obtain the Transrcript 
                    hr = cpStream->QueryInterface(&cpTranscript);

                    // Clear Transcript and Append trainingText to stream                      
                    hr = cpTranscript->AppendTranscript(NULL);
                    hr = cpTranscript->AppendTranscript(TrText);

                    // explicitly close the file-based stream to flush file data and allow app to immediately use the file
                    hr = cpStream->Close();
                    ::CoTaskMemFree(lpFileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


CreateRecoEngine sets everything up from default Speech Profile.  Callback made for success to c# app.
void CreateRecoEngine(void(*callback)(bool))
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create InprocRecognizer
    hr = cpRecognizer2.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpInprocRecognizer);

    // Query ISpRecognizer for use with ISpRecognizer2 to access SetTrainingState
    hr = cpRecognizer2.QueryInterface<ISpRecognizer>(&cpRecognizer);

    // Get the default audio input token.
    hr = SpGetDefaultTokenFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOIN, &cpObjectToken);

    // Set the audio input to our token.
    hr = cpRecognizer->SetInput(cpObjectToken, TRUE);

    // Create the default audio input object.
    hr = SpCreateDefaultObjectFromCategoryId(SPCAT_AUDIOIN, &cpAudio);

    // Set the audio input to our object.
    hr = cpRecognizer->SetInput(cpAudio, TRUE);

    // Get the default recognition profile
    hr = SpGetDefaultTokenFromCategoryId(SPCAT_RECOPROFILES, &cpRecoProfile);

    // Assign the default recognition profile to recognizer
    hr = cpRecognizer->SetRecoProfile(cpRecoProfile);

    // Set Reco state to Active always
    hr = cpRecognizer->SetRecoState(SPRST_ACTIVE_ALWAYS);

    // Create recognition context
    hr = cpRecognizer->CreateRecoContext(&cpRecoContext);

    // Set up the grammar
    hr = cpRecoContext->CreateGrammar(1, &cpRecoGrammar);

    // Load a simple dictation grammar
    hr = cpRecoGrammar->LoadDictation(NULL, SPLO_STATIC);

    // Turn on training
    hr = cpRecognizer2->SetTrainingState(TRUE, TRUE);

    // Activate retained audio settings with default format (that is, SR engine recognition format).
    hr = cpRecoContext->SetAudioOptions(SPAO_RETAIN_AUDIO, &GUID_NULL, NULL);

    // Run recognition loop on seperate thread
    running = true;
    loopThread = std::thread(LoopFunction);

    callback(true);
}


StartListening gets the Training Text from the c# app and feeds it into a global variable for use in the LoopFunciton.
void StartListening(const char* trainingText)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Set global variable to traingText
    TrText = trainingText;

    // Activate the grammar
    hr = cpRecoGrammar->SetDictationState(SPRS_ACTIVE);
}


void StopListening()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Stop recognition loop
    running = false;

    // Turn off dictation
    hr = cpRecoGrammar->SetDictationState(SPRS_INACTIVE);
    
    // Turn off Training
    hr = cpRecognizer2->SetTrainingState(FALSE, TRUE); 
}


